# Programming "program_usb_boot_timeout=1" is a bust!

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch

I have a properly formatted SATA HDD with the newest edition of Raspbian on it and am using a USB-SATA converter (with independent 12 v power supply) to connect it to my Pi 3. I successfully set the OTP bit and got a successfull USB flashdrive boot, so that checks out.

But the issue is that my HDD and USB-SATA get-up is too slow and doesn't respond within the allocated 2 seconds when the Pi boots. I read and read and reread the Official Raspberry Pi Documentation on GitHub and attempted to set the "program_usb_boot_timeout=1" at least 3 times, and still it won't work. I also read [Raspberry Pi 3 USB booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53857/raspberry-pi-3-usb-booting) , too.

Basicaly as superuser, I added "program_usb_boot_timeout=1" (without the quotation marks) to the /boot/config.txt on my Pi's SD card, saved the file, and rebooted.

Than I  checked the status of the bit with "vcgencmd otp_dump | grep 66". No dice each time. All I got was "66:01009daa"

So what gives? what else can I do? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: by the way ... `66:01009daa` ... that `1` there means you've set it correctly - what value were you expecting? the issue is that 5 seconds isn't enough? or perhaps your HDD image is in some way wrong

Comment: ok thank you. i wasn't aware of that. So than that narrows it down to the fact that my USB-SATA converter is to slow or my disc is too slow. thanks

Comment: perhaps you've created the "image" incorrectly on the HDD

Comment: I am going to check that tonight. I'm cheep; I wont buy a new one unless I have to.